# Representing "logged in" and "logged out" in Redux & Typescript to avoid excessive checks in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, store

I'm creating a webapp using React & Redux. I have two main "states" to represent - Logged In and Logged Out.

I'm currently representing this as a union `type State = LoggedIn | LoggedOut` in my Redux store, where each state is discriminated by a `type` parameter:

```
interface LoggedIn {
    type: "LOGGED_IN"
    username: string
}


interface LoggedOut {
    type: "LOGGED_OUT"
}
```

When I'm writing `mapStateToProps` I need to handle the case where the state is `LoggedOut`, even when a route has already been authenticated (i.e. it'll never be provided the state `LoggedOut`), which means I do a lot of checks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
    username: state.type === "LOGGED_IN" ? state.username : ""
})
```

The second conditional path `: ""` would never be run, but the compiler doesn't know this.

How can I represent this better? Can I use Typescript's type system to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Action `type` is used in reducer to distinguish between different actions. Commonly it is not saved in state.
2. In response to action with `type==="LOGGED_IN"` you change state in reducer so Redux (state) knows that user is already logged in.

Your reducer and state can be

```
interface UserState {
  userName?: string;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

const initalUserState: UserState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
}

type KnownActions = LoggedIn | LoggedOut;

const reducer: Reducer<UserState, KnownActions> = (state = initalUserState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) { // Here is type comes into play
    case 'LOGGED_IN':
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true, userName: action.userName }
    case 'LOGGED_OUT':
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: false, userName: undefined }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

If you're using React router you can create private route which will display component with data only for logged in user. For example

```
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'

interface PrivateRouteOwnProps {
    Render: ((props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => React.ReactNode)
}

interface PrivateRouteStateProps {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

type PrivateRouteProps = PrivateRouteOwnProps & PrivateRouteStateProps & RouteProps

const PrivateRoute: FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({Render, isLoggedIn, ...rest}) => {
    return <Route {...rest}
        render={() => (
            isLoggedIn ? 
                Render(props)
                :
                <Redirect to={"/home"}/>
        )}
        />
}

export default connect((state) => ({isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn}))(PrivateRoute)
```

And usage

```
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/page1' Render=(() => <Page1/>)/>
// ...
</Switch>
```

Now `<Page1/>` will only be rendered for logged in user. And in case of logout user will be redirected to '/home`.